# How does Python ensure the return value of __len__ is an integer when len is called?

Tags: python, class, operator-overloading

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data
```

If I run this by passing a string in for `data` I get an error when calling `len` on an instance of this class. Specifically I get `'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

So does the `return` statement in `__len__` have to be an integer? I would think if I am overriding it, it should be able to output whatever I want, so why is this not possible?

Comment: You can return whatever you want from `__len__`, but that doesn't mean `len` is going to accept it. `len` isn't just `def len(x): return x.__len__()`.

Comment: As per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__), the function **should** return an integer >= 0. This means that if you don't do that, things are not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

At the C-level, Python inserts `__len__` into a special slot that catches the output of the call to `__len__` and does some validation on it to ensure it is correct.

---

**LONG ANSWER**

In order to answer this, we have to go a bit down the rabbit hole of what happens under the hood when [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) is called in Python.

First, let's establish some behavior.

```
>>> class foo:
...     def __init__(self, data):
...         self.data = data
...     def __len__(self):
...         return self.data
...
>>> len(foo(-1))
Traceback:
...
ValueError: __len__() should return >= 0
>>> len(foo('5'))
Traceback:
...
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>> len(foo(5))
5
```

When you call [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), the C function [`builtin_len`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1477) gets called.  Let's take a look at this.

```
static PyObject *
builtin_len(PyObject *module, PyObject *obj)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=fa7a270d314dfb6c input=bc55598da9e9c9b5]*/
{
    Py_ssize_t res;

    res = PyObject_Size(obj);  // <=== THIS IS WHAT IS IMPORTANT!!!
    if (res < 0 && PyErr_Occurred())
        return NULL;
    return PyLong_FromSsize_t(res);
}
```

You will notice that the [`PyObject_Size`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/abstract.c#L45) function is being called - this function will return the size of an arbitrary Python object. Let's move further down the rabbit hole.

```
Py_ssize_t
PyObject_Size(PyObject *o)
{
    PySequenceMethods *m;

    if (o == NULL) {
        null_error();
        return -1;
    }

    m = o->ob_type->tp_as_sequence;
    if (m && m->sq_length)
        return m->sq_length(o);  // <==== THIS IS WHAT IS IMPORTANT!!!

    return PyMapping_Size(o);
}
```

It checks if the type defines the `sq_length` function (sequence length), and if so, calls it to get the length. It appears that at the C level, Python categorizes all objects that define `__len__` as either sequences or mappings (even if that's not how we would think of them at the Python level); in our case, Python thinks of this class a sequence, so it calls `sq_length`.

---

Let's take a quick aside: for builtin types (such as [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#list), [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#set), etc.) Python does not actually call a function to calculate the length, but accesses a value stored in a C struct, making this very fast. Each of these builtin types defines how to access this by assigning an accessor method to `sq_length`.  Let's take a quick peek at [how this is implemented for lists](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/listobject.c#L397):

```
static Py_ssize_t
list_length(PyListObject *a)
{
    return Py_SIZE(a);  // <== THIS IS A MACRO for (PyVarObject*) a->ob_size;
}

static PySequenceMethods list_as_sequence = {
    ...
    (lenfunc)list_length,                       /* sq_length */
    ...
};
```

`ob_size` stores the object's size (i.e. number of elements in the list). So, when `sq_length` is called, it is sent to the `list_length` function to get the value of `ob_size`.

---

OK, so that's how it is done for a builtin type... how does it work for a custom class like our `foo`?  Since the "dunder methods" (such as `__len__`) are special, Python detects them in our classes and treats them specially (specifically, inserting them into special slots).

Most of this is handled in [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/typeobject.c). The `__len__` function is intercepted and assigned to the `sq_length` slot (just like a builtin!) [near the bottom of the file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L6706).

```
SQSLOT("__len__", sq_length, slot_sq_length, wrap_lenfunc,
       "__len__($self, /)\n--\n\nReturn len(self)."),
```

The [`slot_sq_length`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/typeobject.c#L5827) function is where we can **finally** answer your question.

```
static Py_ssize_t
slot_sq_length(PyObject *self)
{
    PyObject *res = call_method(self, &PyId___len__, NULL);
    Py_ssize_t len;

    if (res == NULL)
        return -1;
    len = PyNumber_AsSsize_t(res, PyExc_OverflowError);  // <=== HERE!!!
    Py_DECREF(res);
    if (len < 0) {  // <== AND HERE!!!
        if (!PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError,
                            "__len__() should return >= 0");
        return -1;
    }
    return len;
}
```

Two things of note here:

1. If a negative number is returned, a `ValueError` is raised with the message `"__len__() should return >= 0"`. This is *exactly* the error received when I tried to call `len(foo(-1))`!
2. Python tries to coerce the return value of `__len__` to a `Py_ssize_t` before returning (`Py_ssize_t` is a *signed* version of `size_t`, which is like a special type of integer that is guaranteed to be able to index things in a container).

OK, let's look at the implementation of [`PyNumber_AsSsize_t`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/abstract.c#L1255).  It's a bit long so I will omit the non-relevant stuff.

```
Py_ssize_t
PyNumber_AsSsize_t(PyObject *item, PyObject *err)
{
    Py_ssize_t result;
    PyObject *runerr;
    PyObject *value = PyNumber_Index(item);
    if (value == NULL)
        return -1;    
    /* OMITTED FOR BREVITY */
```

The relevant bit here is in [`PyNumber_Index`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/abstract.c#L1213), which Python uses to convert arbitrary objects to integers suitable for indexing.  **Here is where the actual answer to your question lies.**  I have annotated a bit.

```
PyObject *
PyNumber_Index(PyObject *item)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;
    if (item == NULL) {
        return null_error();
    }

    if (PyLong_Check(item)) {  // IS THE OBJECT ALREADY AN int? IF SO, RETURN IT NOW.
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;
    }
    if (!PyIndex_Check(item)) {  // DOES THE OBJECT DEFINE __index__? IF NOT, FAIL.
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "'%.200s' object cannot be interpreted "
                     "as an integer", item->ob_type->tp_name);
        return NULL;
    }
    result = item->ob_type->tp_as_number->nb_index(item);
    if (!result || PyLong_CheckExact(result))
        return result;
    if (!PyLong_Check(result)) {  // IF __index__ DOES NOT RETURN AN int, FAIL.
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                     "__index__ returned non-int (type %.200s)",
                     result->ob_type->tp_name);
        Py_DECREF(result);
        return NULL;
    }
    /* Issue #17576: warn if 'result' not of exact type int. */
    if (PyErr_WarnFormat(PyExc_DeprecationWarning, 1,
            "__index__ returned non-int (type %.200s).  "
            "The ability to return an instance of a strict subclass of int "
            "is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version of Python.",
            result->ob_type->tp_name)) {
        Py_DECREF(result);
        return NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Based on the error that you received, we can see that `'5'` does not define `__index__`.  We can verify that for ourselves:

```
>>> '5'.__index__()
Traceback:
...
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__index__'
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response. Cool to see all the stuff going on behind the scenes to make python work.

Comment: Very detailed explanation .But can someone explain it in one paragraph or less?

Comment: @AnshumanJayaprakash That’s what the “TL;DR” (“too long; didn’t read”) paragraph at the top of the answer is for.

Comment: @AnshumanJayaprakash I changed to wording at the top to make it clear that the first paragraph is a summary.

Comment: Very illuminating deep dive.  Taught me some things I didn't know.