# Drawbacks of using <= operator instead of == plus an assumption

Tags: python

I have been part of a code review in which I have a condition such as this one (Python code):

```
my_list = <whatever list>

if len(my_list) <= 0:
    do_something()
```

I have been pointed out that the condition should be `==` instead of `<=` as a list cannot have a negative length. I have no issues with it in this case, but I wanted to know if there is really any drawbacks on using `<=`.

Here is my rationale on why to use `<=`:

1. The actual condition that I want to check is `not len(my_list) > 0` which is equivalent to `len(my_list) <= 0`, so that is correct for sure.
2. As explained in point 1, `len(my_list) == 0` alone is not equivalent to the original condition. It is in this case, but it is not trivial why it is this way. `len()` returns the value returned by `__len__()` which may be an arbitrary. It only happens to be equivalent because the `len()` implementation performs some validations on the value. One could argue that `len()` implementation may change in the future, so the equivalence would not hold anymore.
3. I feel `len(my_list) <= 0` would be safer in general than using `len(my_list) == 0` plus an assumption that might not hold in some edge or unexpected cases.

So, are my arguments correct? Do you know any drawbacks of using `len(my_list) <= 0`?

Sorry if this seems like a non-relevant question, but this have been raised to me more than once on code reviews so wanted to understand if there is something I am missing.

Comment: The len() function is a builtin of python and therefore expected to work properly, so the assumption that len does not return negative is always true. `<=` might look safer but it isn't and it might confuse others who have to read your code.

Comment: If `len()`'s behavior were to change, it would break a lot of code, so they won't change it. Also, you should write your `if` as `if mylist:` and leave `len()` out of it; a container with no items is falsy, while a container with at least one item is truthy.

Comment: @kindall that's true + it is safer if the list may be `None`.

Comment: @Raphael I can understand the point. `<=` hints that the value may be negative, which could be confusing.

Comment: @Raphael the `len` function calls the objects dunder function `__len__` which is free to return a negative number if it wants. No change to Python required.

Comment: To me this is just defensive programming and should be encouraged, not squashed.

Comment: len() checks the output of __len__() and prohibits negative or invalid return values. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42522863/9173710

Comment: @Raphael that was a great find and interesting read, thanks.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah it definitely is, I also didn't think the limits are basically hard-coded even for custom objects.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some more digging I found this in the python PEP 8 programming recommendations (https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

```py
# Not recommended
my_list = []
if not len(my_list):
    print('List is empty!')

# Recommended
my_list = []
if not my_list:
    print('List is empty!')
```

so now you know the most pythonic way to check if a list is empty!

After testing a bit, I found this works even for custom classes! But my test might be incomplete.

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self, len):
        self.len = len

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len


t1 = Test(3)
if len(t1):
    print("len1 > 0")
if t1:
    print("len2 > 0")

t1 = Test(0)
if len(t1):
    print("len3 > 0")
if t1:
    print("len4 > 0")

t1 = Test(-1)
if len(t1):
    print("len5 > 0")
```

prints

```
len1 > 0
len2 > 0

Exception has occurred: ValueError
__len__() should return >= 0
```

Comment: Link to the PEP 8 doc in case you want the link handy: https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/

Comment: thanks, its sometimes hard to find the original sources for all these python docs, because there are a million pages telling you the same stuff :). I replaced my link with yours!