# Python cant get isdigit() work with len()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok ran into wall too much. Could use some help. Thank you

```
def code(text: str) -> str:
emp_str = ""

    for m in text:
        if m.isdigit():  # Picks the numbers from text.
            emp_str = emp_str + m
            if 0 < len(emp_str) < 11:
                return "Not enough numbers!"
            if len(emp_str) > 11:
                return "Too many numbers!"
    else:
        return emp_str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    print(code(""))
    print(code("123456789123456789"))"
    print(code("ID code is: 49403136526"))
    print(code("efs4  9   #4aw0h 3r 1a36g5j2!!6-"))
```

**End result should be:**

```
Not enough numbers!
Too many numbers!
49403136526
49403136526
```

**But instead i get:**

```
Not enough numbers!
Not enough numbers!
Not enough numbers!
```

It semi works if i change this part of the code len(emp_str) < 11: to if len(emp_str) < 0:

Result:

```
Too many numbers!
49403136526
49403136526
```

Edited what i ment was the results look like the first line print answer is missing i know that len("") is 0.

Comment: Trace through your code line-by-line. The first time we find a digit and go into your `if` statement, what will `len(emp_str)` be?

Comment: You are checking the string length in every iteration. Do it after the loop is complete.

Comment: The string `'First answer missing.'` does not appear in the question.  If you are running code that is different from what is in the question, you are making us guess what those differences could be.  I recommend editing to make sure your question contains a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe there was an if statement you left out which was supposed to return 'First answer missing.' if len(emp_str) == 0. Because otherwise I would have expected it to return "Not enough numbers!" for that case, but you explicitly ruled it out.

Comment: emp_str = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), text))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong: you return a message only when some character `isdigit`. First loop over the text and then assess the number of digits. Also don't forget to check for 0 in condition `if 0 <= len(s) < 11`. Try following code:

```
s = ''
for m in text:
    if m.isdigit():
        s += m
if 0 <= len(s) < 11:
    return "Not enough numbers!"
elif len(s) >= 11:
    return "Too many numbers!"
return s
```

Comment: im such an idiot, yeah it works now  just had to move IF-s  back a little just like FOR. Weird i was messing with them earlier and for what ever reasons Pycharm kept throwing warnings at me.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `re`, I think. Like this:

```
import re

def code2(text: str):
    matches = re.findall("\\d", text)
    num_digits = len(matches) if matches else 0
    if 0 <= num_digits < 11:
        return "Not enough numbers!"
    if num_digits > 11:
        return "Too many numbers!"

    return "".join(matches)
```

Comment: I'd get rid of the 0 <= comparison altogether, unless len is capable of returning a negative number. (Which in current implementations can't happen according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521449/how-does-python-ensure-the-return-value-of-len-is-an-integer-when-len-is-cal

Answer (score 0):

I've never had much luck with isdigit(). I use a try/except statement to accomplish this

```
def code(text: str) -> str:
    emp_str = ""

    for m in text:
        try:
            int_buffer = int(m). # try to make string into an integer
            emp_str = emp_str + m
            if len(emp_str) > 11:
                return "Too many numbers!"
            if not len(emp_str):
                return "Not enough numbers!"
        except Value error:
            pass
    return emp_str

if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(code(""))
    print(code("123456789123456789"))"
    print(code("ID code is: 49403136526"))
    print(code("efs4  9   #4aw0h 3r 1a36g5j2!!6-"))
```